# Validate one button is clicked before another with Javascript

Tags: javascript, vb.net, extjs, webforms

This is in ASP.NET. We are using a ExtJS frontend, and have our own VB.NET controls to make all the Ext Forms and stuff. However, I hope this can be done in plain javascript. There is already some Javascript on the page for the 'Test Connection' button click and handling the result.

However, I need validation on the screen to make sure that a user tests the connection BEFORE saving the screen. (Hits the test button before hitting the save button) -- EACH time they visit the screen.

Here is the code for the page:

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" Inherits="Core.Web.EditBaseView" %>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        function testConnection() {

            Global.mask('Testing Connection...');
            KBBConnectorController.TestConnection(function(result) { testConnectionCallback(result) });
        }

        function testConnectionCallback(result) {
            Global.unmask();
            if (result.Data.Result) {
                Global.alert("Connection to KBB Successful.");
            }
            else {
                Global.alertError(result.Data.Messages[0].Text, result.Data.ExceptionId);
            }
        }

        function Validate() {

        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div style="display:none">
        <%  =Html.DropDownList("ddlMarketValues", TryCast(Model.MarketValues, SelectList))%>
    </div>
    <div>
        <%
            Using KBBForm As New WebControls.Forms.Form
                With KBBForm
                    .OnValidate = "Validate"
                    .ID = "KBB"
                    .ItemName = "connector"
                    With .Toolbar
                        .UseDefaultButtons = False
                        .AddButton(Forms.FormToolbar.ButtonType.Save)
                        .AddButton(Forms.FormToolbar.ButtonType.Cancel)
                        .AddButton("Test Connection", "testConnection", "icon-button-testconnection", , "Test connectione")
                    End With

                    With .CenterRegion
                        .Id = "centerRegion"
                        With .AddFieldSet("Activate Service")
                            .Id = "activate"
                            .LabelWidth = 0
                            Dim cb As New Forms.Control("IsActive", "", "", Model.IsActive, Forms.Control.ControlType.CheckBox)
                            cb.BoxLabel = "Activate Service"
                            .AddControl(cb)
                        End With

                        With .AddFieldSet("Connection Parameters")
                            .Id = "params"
                            .LabelWidth = 150
                            .AddControl(New Forms.Control("UserName", "", "User Name", Model.UserName, Forms.Control.ControlType.TextField))
                            .AddControl(New Forms.Control("Password", "", "Password", Model.Password, Forms.Control.ControlType.Password))
                            .AddControl(New Forms.Control("LoginUrl", "", "URL", Model.LoginUrl))
                            With .AddControl(New Forms.Control("ddlMarketValues", "", "Market Value", , Forms.Control.ControlType.ComboBox))
                                .Id = "ddlMarketValues"
                            End With
                        End With
                    End With
                    Response.Write(.ToString)
                End With
            End Using
            %>    
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see I put an OnValidate function in there but it's blank, and you can see that it's tied to the Form as well. I tried fooling around with that but I could only put something together that would ask me to test every single time I clicked Save, and it wouldn't know if I already tested or not.

Any help? Thanks ahead of time.

-Scott

Comment: You could have the second button disabled, and only enable it after a successful test.

Comment: Can't do that because the boss says it doesn't match with the rest of the code. The way we handle things =/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uh, this should work if I did understand you correctly.

1. In the code which handles the result of the `connection test`, set a flag that indicates that the connection has been tested.
2. In the handler of the `Save` button check for that flag, and if it's not set display a message of some kind instead of actually performing the saving operation.

Your flag could be global variable which is initially set to `false` this way the user would be required to run the test each time the visit the page.

As on how you would override/intercept the Save buttons handler... uh... guess you'll have to extend the VB stuff for that.

Comment: I did all of that and covered the parts you were not too sure about. Instead of setting a flag I set a hidden control.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why not just hide the save button until the test connection is pressed and the connection works?